# Why is Scala asIstanceOf seemingly ignored?

Tags: scala

Trying this:

```
object Box {
  val stuff:Any = "something"
  def foo[T]():T = {
    val z = stuff
    println(s"z = $z   class = ${z.getClass.getName}")
    val y = z.asInstanceOf[T]
    println(s"y = $y   class = ${y.getClass.getName}")
    y
  }
}

println(Box.foo[Boolean]())
```

When run I get output:

```
z = something   class = java.lang.String
y = something   class = java.lang.String
```

So even though stuff is of type Any, it does know that z (assigned from stuff) is a String.  I'm clearly trying to cast this to T, which is clearly Boolean from my println statement.  Why doesn't this blow up?  Why does it think y is a String?

If I hardwire the T's in foo() to Boolean I get the expected failure output:

```
z = something   class = java.lang.String
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToBoolean(BoxesRunTime.java:85)
    ...
```

It's like it totally ignores my .asInstanceOf[T].  Why?

Comment: Thanks to partial type erasure, it's impossible for `.asInstanceOf[T]` to do anything. Casts to generic types don't work in Java either. It's a limitation of the JVM. Doesn't the compiler give you a warning on that line?

Comment: On `2.12.0-M3`, I get `<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : y.type (with underlying type Boolean)
 required: T
            y
            ^` when replacing `val y = z.asInstanceOf[T]`'s `T` with `Boolean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris Martin mentioned this happens because of type erasure. However in scala it is possible to tell the compiler to save the erased types by using `ClassTag`

I modified your code a bit as an example, if you run this you will get a ClassCastException

```
object Box {
  val stuff: Any = "something"
  def foo[T](implicit ev: ClassTag[T]): T = {
    val z = stuff
    println(s"z = $z   class = ${z.getClass.getName}")
    val y = ev.runtimeClass.cast(z)
    println(s"y = $y   class = ${y.getClass.getName}")
    z.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
println(Box.foo[Boolean])
```